# Why does the recommended Drupal install method with Composer use dev for the stability flag?

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

I'm learning PHP Composer, and have run through several scenarios installing Drupal 8 with it. The most authorative method I found for doing so is at drupal.org in [this article](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#download-core).

It suggests the following command to do the initial install:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev my_site_name_dir --stability dev --no-interaction
```

I read up on the stability flag, wondering if I am not understanding it correctly. The most autoritative documentation I found is in [this article](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability). If I am reading and understanding things correctly, dev stability means I am willing to accept dev packages as part of my install.

Am I understanding the flag correctly? Is the assumption here that I am running a dev environment only, but for production I'll use different parameters? As far as I know, I should not be using any dev packages on production servers... they don't even get security advisories.

Would love it if someone could give me a digest on what the correct logic in approaching stability is. And, if that doesn't make it obvious as to why dev is the default recommended stability, the reason why dev is suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--stability dev` switch does not have any effect in this case, so I would guess this is some leftover from old days (or the result of a lack of understanding how `stability` flags works in composer). In [`composer.json`](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/c1e2b6e6b32d51e75321d76c503714d8515e2420/composer.json#L35-L36) of this project there is already defined this setting:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

Command explicitly uses dev branch (`8.x-dev`), so `--stability dev` does not really do anything. And thanks to [`prefer-stable`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable) settings it does not work that bad as you may think - Composer will install dev version only for dependencies without stable releases (which seems to be only `dev` dependencies in this case).

But you shouldn't use this command for production installation anyway, since it installs all dev dependencies. You should probably use something like this:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev my_site_name_dir --no-dev --no-interaction
```

or call `composer install --no-dev` after project initialization.